# Using psycopg2 and Qthreads together(or just postgresql and qthreads) and updating GUI

Tags: python, postgresql, qt, psycopg2, qthread

The orderbook in DB always shows the right orderbook, i just want to continually update it in a GUI. I've been trying to get this to work but when i try to run a cur statement the app just crashes. I suspect i need some help to not have to clear the tableelement each time too, but only update items that have changed(i'm assuming this is a smart thing but im not sure). If i have to use Qt's postgresql lib i will, but then you have to help me how to get that running :)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
import psycopg2
import sys
import time
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=myDb user=kris")
cur = conn.cursor()

class Ui_MainWindow(QThread):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 711, 481))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Sum', 'Total', 'Size', 'Bid'])
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.btnBuy = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBuy.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 91, 33))
        self.btnBuy.setObjectName("btnBuy")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 29))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBuy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BUY"))


class MainUIClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.threadclass.updateTable.connect(self.updateTable)

    def updateTable(self, val):
        print(val)
        if 'setRowCount' in val:
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(val['setRowCount'])
        elif 'insertRow' in val:
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(val['insertRow'])
        elif 'setItem' in val:
            rowNum = val['setItem'][0]
            colNum = val['setItem'][1]
            data = val['setItem'][2]
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowNum, colNum+2,     QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    updateTable = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        cur.execute("select quantity, rate from orderbook where type = %s and market = %s order by rate asc limit 10;", (0, "BTC-ADA"))
        orderbook = cur.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        for rowNum, rowData in enumerate(orderbook):
            self.updateTable.emit({"insertRow": 0})
            for colNum, data in enumerate(rowData):
                self.updateTable.emit({"setItem": [rowNum, colNum, data]})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainUIClass()
    app.show()
    #a.exec_()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the database connection before Qt's main loop is started, move all Postgres related stuff into the thread.

```
class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    updateTable = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=XXX user=YYYY password=ZZZ host=localhost port=5555")
        
        cur = conn.cursor()        
        cur.execute("select * from events")
        orderbook = cur.fetchall()
        
        for rowNum, rowData in enumerate(orderbook):
            self.updateTable.emit({"insertRow": 0})
            for colNum, data in enumerate(rowData):
                self.updateTable.emit({"setItem": [rowNum, colNum, data]})
        
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Ah, that actually worked. Should have tried that after reading the docs, instead searching endlessly to find the "best" solution... Anyway. What this leaves me is only data for the 10'th row...

Comment: Ok! Got that working. The next loop obviously used the "old" rowNum since it was looping inside of the other loop. Do you know how i can only update new values, or should i just clear the table every time and put in new values?

Comment: I prefer the lazy way: Clear the table and reload everything :)

Comment: Ah. I found out i didn't have to "clear". I just had to input new values. I suppose i can still improve it vy saving the initial values and only calling an "emit" when the data has changed. Thanks for your help!